# gradle init - generate LF line ending on windows

Tags: gradle

I wonder if it is possible to convince gradle to generate on Windows files with Linux line endings (LF) instead of (CRLF), while running `gradle init`.

It is interesting, that the generated *.java files have LF line endings, while build.gradle, git-related etc files have CRLF... I would prefer though to have all LF (except maybe gradle.cmd).